# Compare the number of significant digits in two numbers

Tags: python

For a coding exercise I'm working on, I'm trying to compare two numbers and choose the one that has the larger number of significant digits.

For example: compare `2.37e+07` and `2.38279e+07`, select `2.38279e+07` because it has more significant digits.

I don't know how to implement this in Python. I considered counting the length of each number using `len(str(NUMBER))`, but this method returns "10" for both of the numbers above because it doesn't differentiate between zero and non-zero digits.

How can I compare the number of significant digits in Python?

Comment: Are you starting from `float` objects or `str` objects?

Comment: If they are `float` then you need to look at the precision of the input numbers not the calculated numbers as they can have an 'artificial number of significant digits'? In fact, the accuracy of the output result is directly related to the accuracy of the input precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty approach might be `len(str(NUMBER).strip('0'))` which will trim off any trailing zeros and count the remaining digits.

To discount the decimal point then you'd need `len(str(NUMBER).replace('.','').strip('0'))`

However you need to bear in mind that in many cases converting a python float to a string can give you some odd behaviour, due to the way floating point numbers are handled.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to go with doing this textually, you can do the following using regular expression:

```
import re

l = re.compile(r'(\d*?)(0*)(\.0?)')

>>> l.match(str(2.37e+07)).groups()[0]
'237'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could try an algorithm like this:

```
sf1 = "2.3723805"
addsf1 = 0
decimal = False
for num in sf1:
    if decimal == True:
        addsf1 = addsf1 + int(num)
    if num == ".":
        decimal = True
print(addsf1)
```

This would check for every letter in the significant number, if you convert it to a string, that is. It will then iterate over every letter until it reaches the decimal part and then it will add the numbers together. You can do this to the other significant figure which can be used to compare the difference between the two. This would tell which one had the larger added numbers.

Not sure if this is the best solution for your problem.